# Jquery .toggleClass() slide position change

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, show-hide, slide, toggleclass

By clicking on the button, the div changes its position through the css attributes. However, I would like the div slides animated from one position to another.

Note: `#window` must have `width:100%;` and `height:100%;`, and the `.closed` position must be `top:-100%;`, cannot work it with 'px'.

style

```
    .open {
    top:0%;
    }

    .closed {
    top:-100%;
    }
```

script

```
$(function() {
        $( "#button" ).click(function(){
            $( "#window" ).toggleClass( "open", "closed" );
            $( "#window" ).toggleClass( "closed", "open" );
            return false;   
        });
    });
```

html

```
<div id="button" style="background:#EEE; cursor:pointer; width: 50px; height:50px; z-index:2;">Window</div>

<div id="window" class="closed" style="position:absolute; background:#000; width: 100%; height:100%; margin-top:-50px; z-index:1;"></div>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: You have to work with pixels. To keep it dynamic you have to get parent div's width/height  by 
`$("#window").parent().width()` and `$("#window").parent().height()`

And instead of toggleClass simply change the top using `.css()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [toggleClass](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/) function, from the jQueryUI library, it supports animation. jQueryUI is a seperate download.

Instead of having two classes ("open" and "closed"), consider to have only the "open" class, and have the element be closed as default. In this way, I believe the toggleClass function will work better.

$('#window').toggleClass("open", 500);

where 500 is the time in milliseconds for the animation to complete.

Answer (score 1):

it is ridiculous for a problem like this using 2 classes and toggleClass method, because jQuery already has methods like toggle(), slideToggle(), fadeToggle(), that can provide absolutely the same result without using any extra classes:

```
$( "#window" ).toggle();
$( "#window" ).slideToggle();
$( "#window" ).fadeToggle();
```